# Is this the right way to use java optional

Tags: java-8

Is this the right way to use java `Optional`?

```
public Optional<DoctorDTO> getPrimaryDoctorDetails(String clientId)
{
  try {

    ps = objDataBaseClass.getPrepareStatement(connection, "QUERY");           
    ps.setString(1, clientId);

    rs = objDataBaseClass.executeQuery(ps);     

    if (rs.next()) 
      doctorDTO.setProviderId(rs.getString("NAME"));               
  } catch (SQLException sqlE) {}   

  Optional<DoctorDTO> optionalDoctor =
      doctorDTO==null ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(doctorDTO);

  return optionalDoctor;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context to explain the code sections. See stackoverflow.com/help for guidance on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

no, you should use

```
Optional.ofNullable(doctorDTO)
```

also return type should be `Optional<DoctorDTO>`. And you should at least log the exception.

Comment: The problem here is that `doctorDTO` is never assigned in the method. There is a method invocation on `doctorDTO` within the method, not checking for `null`, which leads to the assumption that it is never `null`. But even if it could be `null`, there’s nothing in the method changing that, so if it is `null`, the method would do entirely obsolete operations before returning an empty optional anyway. Even worse, when it is non-`null`, multiple invocations of this method will manipulate the same object…